# Handling multiple forms of different form tags in a function view in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django-views, django-forms

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="p_formUpload">
{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset class="form-group">
<p>
{ p_form|crispy }}
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="c_formUpload">
{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset class="form-group">
<p>
{{ c_form|crispy }}
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**views.py:**

```
def profile(request):
p_photos = ProfilePicture.objects.all()
c_photos = CoverPicture.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                request.FILES,
                                instance=request.user.profilepicture)
    c_form = CoverUpdateForm(request.POST,
                             request.FILES,
                             instance=request.user.coverpicture)
    if p_form.is_valid():
        p_form.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Your account has been successfully updated!')
        return redirect('profile')
    if c_form.is_valid():
        c_form.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Your account has been successfully updated!')
        return redirect('profile')
else:
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profilepicture)
    c_form = CoverUpdateForm(instance=request.user.coverpicture)

context={
    'p_form' : p_form,
    'c_form' : c_form,
    'p_photos': p_photos,
    'c_photos': c_photos,
}
return render(request, 'user/profile.html',context)
```

**Javascript**

```
<script src="{% static 'user/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'user/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'user/js/cropper.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script>
      $(function () {
        $("#id_profile_image").change(function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("#image").attr("src", e.target.result);
            $("#modalCrop").modal("show");
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
      });

      var $image = $("#image");
      var cropBoxData;
      var canvasData;
      $("#modalCrop").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
        $image.cropper({
          viewMode: 1,
          aspectRatio: 1/1,
          minCropBoxWidth: 200,
          minCropBoxHeight: 200,
          ready: function () {
            $image.cropper("setCanvasData", canvasData);
            $image.cropper("setCropBoxData", cropBoxData);
          }
        });
      }).on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        cropBoxData = $image.cropper("getCropBoxData");
        canvasData = $image.cropper("getCanvasData");
        $image.cropper("destroy");
      });

      $(".js-zoom-in").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("zoom", 0.1);
      });

      $(".js-zoom-out").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("zoom", -0.1);
      });

      $(".js-crop-and-upload").click(function () {
        var cropData = $image.cropper("getData");
        $("#id_x").val(cropData["x"]);
        $("#id_y").val(cropData["y"]);
        $("#id_height").val(cropData["height"]);
        $("#id_width").val(cropData["width"]);
        $("#p_formUpload").submit();
      });

    });
    </script>
        <script>
      $(function () {
        $("#id_cover_image").change(function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("#c-image").attr("src", e.target.result);
            $("#c-modalCrop").modal("show");
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
      });

      var $image = $("#c-image");
      var cropBoxData;
      var canvasData;
      $("#c-modalCrop").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
        $image.cropper({
          viewMode: 1,
          aspectRatio: 11/4,
          minCropBoxWidth: 1100,
          minCropBoxHeight: 400,
          ready: function () {
            $image.cropper("setCanvasData", canvasData);
            $image.cropper("setCropBoxData", cropBoxData);
          }
        });
      }).on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        cropBoxData = $image.cropper("getCropBoxData");
        canvasData = $image.cropper("getCanvasData");
        $image.cropper("destroy");
      });

      $(".c-js-zoom-in").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("zoom", 0.1);
      });

      $(".c-js-zoom-out").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("zoom", -0.1);
      });

      $(".c-js-crop-and-upload").click(function () {
        var cropData = $image.cropper("getData");
        $("#id_x").val(cropData["x"]);
        $("#id_y").val(cropData["y"]);
        $("#id_height").val(cropData["height"]);
        $("#id_width").val(cropData["width"]);
        $("#c_formUpload").submit();
      });

    });
    </script>
```

I am trying to have both the form in same page but in different form tag. But my first form(p_form) is submitting data but second form(c_form) is not working.
My problem looks like in the views.py.
I tried to find many solutions bit could'nt find it.
I have multiple submit buttons through javascript and have two forms in the same page in different tags.
Modules used in the project for django, crispy_forms, pillow.
My complete code can be found at https://github.com/otakliquekirito/otaklique

Comment: Share forms.py code it seems there might be the error :(

Comment: I tried my c_form in another page...it worked...so I think my error is in views.py because on bringing c_form at the front it is working

Comment: Ok let's see wait

Comment: Have u added both submit buttons in a proper way?

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly when kept in different pages

Comment: What exactly do you mean "second form(c_form) is not working"?

Comment: @JohnGordon my p_form is submitting data, but the other form c_form is not submitting the data,c_form and p_form worked perfectly when kept in different pages

Comment: Or just try creating a submit button via HTML and submit simple :)

Comment: If this also doesn't works then I need to go through all code.

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ I tried the submit button as well but it did'nt work...I want to keep both the forms in the same page

Comment: could you please share your repo or code? I will try it

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ from where should I share it

Comment: As shown, those forms do not have submit buttons.  How are you submitting the forms?  If you're using Enter to submit the form, then that may be the problem -- as I recall, pressing Enter submits the _first_ form on the page.

Comment: @JohnGordon I am submitting it by javascript...I'll update the code and add javascript...just a minute

Comment: @BickeyJaiswal share it as github repo

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ (https://github.com/otakliquekirito/otaklique) here's my code...sorry for the delay

Comment: the problem is in views.py you are just redirecting when first form is submitted so the second one is not submitted simple

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ but the form is only redirected if my p_form is_valid()

Comment: Yes if any of the form data is valid it will be redirected

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ thats what I want to do...but its not working...1st form submit data but 2nd form dose'nt

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                request.FILES,
                                instance=request.user.profilepicture)
    c_form = CoverUpdateForm(request.POST,
                             request.FILES,
                             instance=request.user.coverpicture)
    if p_form.is_valid() and c_form.is_valid():
        p_form.save()
        c_form.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Your account has been successfully updated!')
        return redirect('profile') 
    elif p_form.is_valid():
        pass
    elif c_form.is_valid():
        pass
```

Comment: this only works when both the forms are valid. If one form is not valid then it does not save

Comment: ha yes just add another condition in elif block

Comment: I want to save p_form if p_form is valid and c_form if c_form is valid. The above code will only work if both the form are submitted at the same time. But my code submits two form at different time.

Comment: will it save my p_form is I submit only p_form